# Getting value of parameter in web.config custom section in mvc View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, web-config

I have custom section in web.config with user roles:

```
  <roles>
     <add key="Role1" value="Dev" />
     <add key="Role2" value="Dev2" />
  </roles>
```

And i want to get value using key in my _layout page. And then hide link in menu depending of roles that user contain. Something like this:

```
     @if (User.IsInRole(@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("roles")["Role1"]))
     {
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("{{'Statistics' | translate}}", "Statistics", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
     }
```

Comment: are you getting any error? your code is not working?

Comment: I an getting error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' AvailibilityTool.API C:\Code\AvailabilityTool2\AvailibilityTool.API\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml ; probably this should be done other way. This code is just to illustrate what i want to do.

Comment: Please start with some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC.  I recommend having a look at the templates within Visual Studio, click New Project > Website > MVC

Comment: GetSection("roles") returns a class representing that section, and within that, there is a property representing the collection, configured as the default, so you have to understand the configuration classes that represent the roles section in order to use it.

Comment: I know how to use it in Controller, but have no idea how do it in View... Obvious problem is lack of parsing from object to for example "NameValueCollection". Unfortunately I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the value directly `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("roles")["Role1"].` Perform type  cast and access the value of key like as below.

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("roles") as NameValueCollection;
var value = section["Role1"];
```

In .cshtml/_Layout page you can use @ symbol like as below.

```
 @{
        var section = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("roles") as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;
        var value = section["Role1"];
  }
```

Comment: I am using it in View. I need cshtml cod, not c#.

Comment: @CapitanPlanet updated the answer with layout page code

Comment: It was not my vote. I cannot vote at all (low reputation). I just marked Your post as answer and posted my final code. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Balaji M!
This is final version of my code:

```
                @{
                var sections = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("roles") as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;
                }

                @if (User.IsInRole(sections["StatistiscRole"]))
                {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("{{'Statistics' | translate}}", "Statistics", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                }
```